# calculate useful order statistics using describe with NaN in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

consider the `df`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed([3,1415])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 10), columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJ'))
```

---

***`describe`***
calculates useful statistics

```
df.describe()
```

[image]

---

***introduce `NaN`***

now consider `d1`

```
d1 = df.mask(np.random.choice([True, False], df.shape, p=[.2, .8]))
d1.describe()
```

[image]

---

I have not calculations for `['25%', '50%', '75%']`
***How do I get these conveniently using pre-existing functions?***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A much cleaner way would be to use the include argument such has:

```
d1.describe(include=['float64'])

Out[214]: 
            A       B       C       D       E       F       G       H       I       J
count 70.0000 77.0000 81.0000 82.0000 78.0000 81.0000 80.0000 82.0000 75.0000 81.0000
mean   0.0572 -0.1383 -0.1550 -0.0658  0.0074 -0.0508 -0.0253 -0.0202 -0.1054  0.1019
std    0.9580  0.9447  1.0263  0.9393  0.8976  0.9207  0.9993  0.9474  1.0305  0.7382
min   -2.3045 -2.3190 -2.2027 -2.8470 -2.7149 -2.4345 -2.3619 -2.0283 -2.1609 -1.6739
25%   -0.5287 -0.6854 -0.9155 -0.8202 -0.5456 -0.6045 -0.6823 -0.6192 -0.9222 -0.3186
50%    0.0581 -0.2999 -0.1799 -0.0525  0.0181 -0.1502 -0.1421 -0.0458 -0.0108  0.1053
75%    0.5510  0.4997  0.5064  0.7505  0.5904  0.5217  0.6515  0.5790  0.6261  0.7041
max    2.6967  2.3198  2.5974  1.8385  2.2225  2.6081  2.4215  2.0045  2.1077  1.9469
```

you could also use the `exclude` argument but it's tricky with NaN values. passing 'bool' works

```
d1.describe(exclude=['bool'])
Out[221]: 
            A       B       C       D       E       F       G       H       I       J
count 70.0000 77.0000 81.0000 82.0000 78.0000 81.0000 80.0000 82.0000 75.0000 81.0000
mean   0.0572 -0.1383 -0.1550 -0.0658  0.0074 -0.0508 -0.0253 -0.0202 -0.1054  0.1019
std    0.9580  0.9447  1.0263  0.9393  0.8976  0.9207  0.9993  0.9474  1.0305  0.7382
min   -2.3045 -2.3190 -2.2027 -2.8470 -2.7149 -2.4345 -2.3619 -2.0283 -2.1609 -1.6739
25%   -0.5287 -0.6854 -0.9155 -0.8202 -0.5456 -0.6045 -0.6823 -0.6192 -0.9222 -0.3186
50%    0.0581 -0.2999 -0.1799 -0.0525  0.0181 -0.1502 -0.1421 -0.0458 -0.0108  0.1053
75%    0.5510  0.4997  0.5064  0.7505  0.5904  0.5217  0.6515  0.5790  0.6261  0.7041
max    2.6967  2.3198  2.5974  1.8385  2.2225  2.6081  2.4215  2.0045  2.1077  1.9469
```

Comment: brilliant!  I debated whether to include my own answer.  I never know if it will discourage or encourage others.  Will select as answer when I can.

Comment: imo it discourages a bite. Normally I wait a couple of minutes before posting my own answer and 95% of the time I am suprise with a answer I did not think of!

Comment: Not working for me yet.  I'm sure it will.  What version of pandas are you using?

Comment: I am using 0.19.0

Comment: @StevenG Why is it tricky with `NaNs`? How about `nan_to_num()` then filter on `num`?

Answer (score 1):

It dawned on me that `stack` removes `NaN` by default.  After I've stacked, I'll have a multiindex in which I can group by one level and calculate stats using `describe`.

```
d1.stack().groupby(level=1).describe().unstack(0)
```

[image]

Notice that all the other statistics are identical and we now have `['25%', '50%', '75%']` filled in.